# Handling of <?> type in Java generics

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have an interface that describes possible request handlers that can service actions requested by a client in the context of some client session state, that is stored by the client:

```java
public interface RequestHandler<State> {
    // Perform action in the context of currentState and return updated state
    public State request(State currentState, String action);
}
```

To make it easy to implement the RequestHandlers, I added the generic type `State`, which encapsulates all the required client session data.

Now, a simple client could look like this:

```java
public class Client {
    private final RequestHandler<?> handler;
    private Object state;

    Client(RequestHandler<?> handler) {
        // Initialize the RequestHandler to use for "go"-requests
        this.handler = handler;
        // Initialize our client state to "null"
        this.state   = null;
    }

    public void go() {
        // Execute "go"-request in current state and update state
        state = handler.request(state, "go");  // <= this is an error (see below)
    }
}
```

During creation it gets provided with a `RequestHandler`, which it then later uses to execute "go"-requests. It also manages storage of its current session state in the private `state` variable.

Now, since my clients shouldn't need to worry about what the session state actually looks like internally, I would like to use `RequestHandler<?>` as shown. But, unfortunately, this gives me an error in the `state = handler.request...` line:

> The method request(capture#3-of ?, String) in the type
>   RequestHandler is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Object, String)

Is there an issue with just changing the offending line to:

```java
state = ((RequestHandler<Object>) handler).request(state, "go");
```

(which turns the error into an "Unchecked cast"-warning)

Clearly, this way I loose type-checking on my `state`-object, but if the `Client` only ever sets it to `null` or something returned by the `RequestHandler`, there should be no problems, right?

I know I could also just parameterize `Client` as `Client<State>` as well and then using `State` in place of `Object` and `?` everywhere. But I would rather like to avoid this, since it's (in my opinion) just dead weight in this case that will have to be carried around wherever a `Client` is instantiated or used...

There is no way to cast `state` to `(?)`, right?

UPDATE:

There's a beautiful solution to this problem if everything was happening inside a single method rather than a class:

```java
public <State> void go(RequestHandler<State> handler) {
    State state = null;
    state = handler.request(state, "go");
    state = handler.request(state, "go again");
    state = handler.request(state, "go one more time");
}
```

This, I can call anywhere without having to always specify what `State` actually is. But there is no equivalent construct for entire classes (some inferred generic argument) is there?

Comment: Making that cast will make you loose your type-safety, as you stated. Why are you trying to use a generic here? It sounds like request only accepts `State` and returns `State`. Is there another situation where a `RequestHandler` will be used for something else?

Comment: @nickrak But it couldn't possibly result in a runtime exception, no matter what parameter `RequestHandler` is actually specified with, correct? (Only, of course, if my `Client` decides to save its own illegal stuff in `state`)

Comment: It would cause a ClassCastException if you passed something that is not a State. This would not be caught at compile time because client is not made aware of the type restriction.

Comment: If the `State` is simply there to store things used on the server that the client does not need to know, why not use a String token and store that state data on the server like an Http Session?

Comment: @nickrak :) This allows me to create a stateless server, which scales much better to many clients. Also, there might be different implementations for `RequestHandler`, including a mock-service for testing purposes that runs entirely client-side.

Comment: If your mock service doesn't accept `State` than it's of little practical use as a testing tool. Your testing classes should implement the exact same interfaces as your functional classes. I agree that being stateless is good for scalability, but if that's the end-goal, why keep the client in the dark about it being a `State` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it would be okay to make `Client` generic, reflecting the type of the `RequestHandler`. But, if you want to hide that inside the client, you can do it like this:

```
public final class Client
{

  private final CaptureHelper<?> helper;

  <T> Client(RequestHandler<T> handler) {
    this.helper = new CaptureHelper<T>(handler);
  }

  public void go()
  {
    helper.request("go");
  }

  private final class CaptureHelper<T>
  {

    private final RequestHandler<T> handler;

    private T state;

    private CaptureHelper(RequestHandler<T> handler) {
      this.handler = handler;
    }

    private void request(String action)
    {
      state = handler.request(state, action);
    }

  }

}
```

Note that this frees anyone using a client from caring about the generic type of its `RequestHandler`. Users would have code like this:

```
RequestHandler<?> handler = ... ;
Client client = new Client(handler); /* Look ma, no generics! */
client.go();
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is the kind of answer I was hoping for. Awesome! Thanks! +1 √ :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your intention is that clients should be able to define `RequestHandler`s that consume and return a variety of objects conforming to a `State` interface. If so, you need to define your interface like this so that the clients can specify the particular `State` type they're using:

```
public interface RequestHandler<StateType> {
    // Perform action in the context of currentState and return updated state
    public StateType request(StateType currentState, String action);
}
```

If your `Client` class is intended to be generic (in the non-technical sense), then it should also be generic (in the technical sense) by allowing subclasses or its own clients to specify the type of the `State` object:

```
public class Client<StateType> {
    private StateType state;
    ...
}
```

The problem with your existing code is that there's absolutely no information contained in an absolute wildcard. When the wildcard represents a return type, it might be the case that you're getting an object of class `Object`, with no useful behavior, and as an argument type, it would basically mean that the client could expect you to supply an object of any specific class but wasn't saying which.

Comment: As an example, let's say my `RequestHandler` provides some sort of key-value store and the `request` method is used to store values. Then, a `Client` won't want care about what exactly is stored in `State`, as long as the put and get `requests` provided by the `RequestHandler` do their job. So, I would like to keep the exact type of `State` away from the client (as also mentioned at the end of my question).

Comment: I'm attempting to understand your question, but it really isn't making much sense. If you have a reason to use generics, use them; otherwise, ditch the generic type on the `RequestHandler`.  Or were you simply asking about a particular use case where your specific `Client` class doesn't care? In that case, use `RequestHandler<Object>`.

Comment: I was just asking about this particular use-case, yep. So using the `(RequestHandler<Object>)` cast that I put in the question is ok? It won't ever fail, no matter what the `<?>` actually is, right?

Comment: As long as you don't ever try to (a) use the object that comes out of the `request` method as anything other than a plain `Object` and (b) never pass anything back into the `RequestHandler` that is the wrong runtime type, no. But the correct approach really is to parameterize `Client`; `Client` doesn't have to understand or care about the generic type that its client is using, just list it.

Comment: I edited my answer to match what I think you're wanting. (Your use of `State` as a generic variable is confusing since it really looks like an `interface` name.) Since the client of `Client` has to declare a generic type for `RequestHandler` anyway, there's no additional complexity to adding the type parameter to your `Client` class.

Comment: I agree that making the Client generic as well would definitely be the most correct solution. The problem is that if I ever implement any specific clients that extend `Client`, I need to always carry that generic parameter around with me everywhere and update it in the appropriate places if I ever change my `RequestHandler`... Just a bit of a mess...

Comment: What do you mean by "carry it around"? Any subclass that used a specific state type could just `extend Client<ConcreteStateClass>`, and if you change an interface, you have to update all of its users anyway.

Comment: I added an update to the question to illustrate what kind of solution I was hoping for, but I'm not sure it's possible...

Comment: Let's say I need to move my `RequestHandler` to a different server infrastructure, which now uses timestamps (Dates) instead of version numbers (Integers) as my client state, but otherwise provides the exact same request handling capabilities, then I need to update all my different client implementations to "support" the new state format, even though technically nothing they need to care about changed for them...